# how to link re2 library in my project like a static library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

My question: in this moment I'm linking the libre2 dinamically, but I want to do this statically. I installed the library in my pc (sudo apt-get install libre2-dev), got the "binary" and linked this binary "libre2.so" in my executable. But I want to git clone the repository or to do this by git submodule, then build this repository and link it in my project statically.

I'm new here and sorry for my bad English rss'

1) my project structure

```
- bin
- build
- external
    - re2
- main.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
- README.md
```

2) CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

project( simmc-agent )

# version number  
set ( VERSION_MAJOR 0 )  
set ( VERSION_MINOR 0 )  

# cpr requires c++11  
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )  

# src : main   
file ( GLOB SOURCES *.cpp )  

# linking res library dinamically  
set(RE2_LIBRARIES -L${RE2_LIBRARY_DIR} -l libre2.so)  

# src : collect functions - depend on OS  
if ( WIN32 )  
    file ( GLOB SOURCES ${SOURCES} src/windows/*.cpp )  
else ()     # if( UNIX )  
    file ( GLOB SOURCES ${SOURCES} src/linux/*.cpp )  
endif ()  

# headers  
include_directories ( "include" )  

# test   
option( PRINT_JSON "Set to ON to print json objects before sending" OFF )  
message(STATUS "${PRINT_JSON}: ${${PRINT_JSON}}")  
if ( PRINT_JSON )  
    add_definitions ( -DPRINT_JSON )  
endif ()  

# compile
set ( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../bin" )
add_executable ( agent-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} ${SOURCES} )  
target_link_libraries ( agent-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} ${RE2_LIBRARY} )
```

3) main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <re2/re2.h>

using namespace std;  
using namespace re2;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {  
    cout << "hello world" << endl;

 int matchResult;

 matchResult = RE2::FullMatch("hello", "h.*o"); 
 cout << "matchResult = " << matchResult << endl;  

   return 0;  

}
```

Comment: To download and build re2 you can use `ExternalProject_Add()`. You can see the examples for your case by looking at these two files: [https://github.com/project-z/mutton/blob/master/ext/re2.cmake](https://github.com/project-z/mutton/blob/master/ext/re2.cmake) and [https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/external/re2.cmake](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/external/re2.cmake)  which also use the static library.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'll try it when I get in home. After that, I'll give the feedback.

Comment: Hey ... I tested it and I have some problems: "It was not possible to meet the -lexternal/re2/src/RE2/obj/so/libre2.so"

Comment: Executing "cmake ..", "external/re2/src/RE2/obj/so/libre2.so", the library is meet. But, executing the "make" command, the following error is apresented: '"/usr/bin/ld: it was not possible to meet -lexternal/re2/src/re2/obj/so/libre2.so" . It's seen that the library have been linking dynamically. I'm so sorry for my english, it's not so good.

Comment: I don't get. Are you using a re2.cmake or not?

Comment: not. It's only one CMakeLists.txt. I have to create a re2.cmake file ? Where I save this file?

Comment: I did the re2.cmake file. I think I did the correct tree directory. But I think the re2.h include it's not be in the libre2.a binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - (26.01.17) : Hello, guys. I'm here to talk how I resolve it.
Following some tips gave here, I create a file called `re2.cmake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8.7 )

if (NOT RE2_NAME)

include (ExternalProject)

SET (RE2_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/re2/src/re2/)
SET (RE2_EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/re2/src/re2/)
SET (RE2_URL https://github.com/google/re2.git)
SET (RE2_BUILD ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/re2/src/re2)  
SET (RE2_LIBRARIES ${RE2_BUILD}/obj/so/libre2.so)
get_filename_component(RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${RE2_BUILD}/libre2.a ABSOLUTE)  
SET (RE2_INCLUDES ${RE2_BUILD})

if ( WIN32 )   
  SET (RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${RE2_BUILD}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/re2.lib) 
else ()   
  SET (RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${RE2_BUILD}/libre2.a) 
endif ()

ExternalProject_Add(RE2      
  PREFIX RE2      
  GIT_REPOSITORY ${RE2_URL}      
  # GIT_TAG ${RE2_TAG}      
  DOWNLOAD_DIR "${DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}"      
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1      
  INSTALL_COMMAND sudo make install     
   CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS         
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release          -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF          -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE:BOOL=ON  
)

 ## put re2 includes in the directory where they are expected  
 add_custom_target(re2_create_destination_dir COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${RE2_INCLUDE_DIR}/re2 DEPENDS re2)   

 add_custom_target(re2_copy_headers_to_destination DEPENDS re2_create_destination_dir)   

 foreach(header_file ${RE2_HEADERS})      
    add_custom_command(TARGET re2_copy_headers_to_destination PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${header_file} ${RE2_INCLUDE_DIR}/re2)  
  endforeach ()   

  ADD_LIBRARY(RE2_LIB STATIC IMPORTED DEPENDS RE2)  
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(RE2_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES})

endif (NOT RE2_NAME)
```

This file download the repository, building and install the library libre2 in my computer. This library has a dependency for Thread library* (I thinks all linux operation system come with this library).

But, has a problem: I only do this, if I'm a root user. Because the library used the "make install" command and to do it, you need to be a root user.

my project structure:

```
- bin
- build
- src
- include
- modules
    - re2.cmake
- CMakeLists.txt
```

FOllowing my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8.7 )

project ( project C CXX)

# version number
SET ( VERSION_MAJOR 0 )
SET ( VERSION_MINOR 0 )

SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )

# src : main
file ( GLOB SOURCES src/main.cpp )

# headers
include_directories ( "include" )

# src : libre2 - Download, build and install the library

find_package (Threads)

include ( "modules/re2.cmake" )
set(RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES -L${RE2_LIBRARY_DIR} -l libre2.a )

# compile 
set ( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../bin" )
add_executable ( project-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries ( project-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} ${RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(project-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} RE2)

target_link_libraries (project-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Answer (score 0):

My new `CmakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.7 )

project( simmc-agent )

# version number
set ( VERSION_MAJOR 0 )
set ( VERSION_MINOR 0 )

# cpr requires c++11
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )

# src : main
file ( GLOB SOURCES *.cpp )

# libre2

if (NOT RE2_NAME)

    include (ExternalProject)

    set(ABBREV "RE2")
    set(EXT_PREFIX "external/re2" )
    set(${ABBREV}_NAME         ${ABBREV})
    set(${ABBREV}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${EXT_PREFIX}/src/re2/)
    set(APP_DEPENDENCIES ${APP_DEPENDENCIES} ${ABBREV})

    message("Installing ${RE2_NAME} into ext build area: ${EXT_PREFIX} ...")

    ExternalProject_Add(RE2
      PREFIX ${EXT_PREFIX}
      URL https://re2.googlecode.com/files/re2-20130115.tgz
      URL_MD5 "ef66646926e6cb8f11f277b286eac579"
      PATCH_COMMAND ""
      CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
      BUILD_COMMAND make
      INSTALL_COMMAND ""
      BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
      )

    set(CXXFLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)

    set(${ABBREV}_LIBRARIES ${EXT_PREFIX}/src/RE2/obj/so/libre2.so)
    set(${ABBREV}_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${EXT_PREFIX}/src/RE2/obj/libre2.a)

    set_target_properties(${RE2_NAME} PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ON)

  endif (NOT RE2_NAME)


if(RE2_INCLUDE_DIRS AND RE2_LIBRARIES)
  set(RE2_FOUND TRUE)
endif(RE2_INCLUDE_DIRS AND RE2_LIBRARIES)

if(RE2_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Found RE2: ${RE2_LIBRARIES}")
else(RE2_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find RE2 library.")
endif(RE2_FOUND)

set(INCLUDES ${INCLUDES} ${RE2_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
# set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES} )

# headers
include_directories ( "include" )

# test 
option( PRINT_JSON "Set to ON to print json objects before sending" OFF )
message(STATUS "${PRINT_JSON}: ${${PRINT_JSON}}")
if ( PRINT_JSON )
    add_definitions ( -DPRINT_JSON )
endif ()

# compile
set ( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../bin" )
add_executable ( agent-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} ${SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries ( agent-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}  ${RE2_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Please replace `target_link_libraries ( agent-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}  ${RE2_LIBRARIES})` with the following: `target_link_libraries ( agent-v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}  ${RE2_STATIC_LIBRARIES})`. That should link the static one! If it works I will write up in answer.

Comment: I made it and continue doesn't working :/ The same error: /usr/bin/ld: not possible to meet  -lexternal/re2/src/re2/obj/libre2.a